# Popover doesn't show the data-content correctly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

In the form there is an input

```
input(rel='popover', data-content='Precio del Alquiler.',type="text",placeholder="Precio del Alquiler",id="precio",name='precio_alquiler')
```

Everything works fine when I call with jQuery the popover bootstrap.

```
$('#precio').popover('show);
```

But I had to correct a problem with the design and I changed the structure of the input like this:

```
div.input-prepend
    span.add-on $
    input.prependedInput(rel='popover', data-content='Precio del Alquiler.',type="text",placeholder="Precio del Alquiler",id="precio",name='precio_alquiler')
```

When I call the jQuery function, the popover shows empty. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for this is simple... just execute the popover in the parent div

```
div.input-prepend(rel='popover', data-content='Precio del Alquiler.')
    span.add-on $
    input.prependedInput(type="text",placeholder="Precio del Alquiler",id="precio",name='precio_alquiler')
```

and the jquery code is

```
$('#precio').parent().popover('show);
```

tnx all